# CodeIgniter get id parameter when using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

When I open a specific customer form, my url changes to something like this:

```
http://localhost/proj/dashboard/customers/edit/1
```

As you can see there's a parameter with the ID (which in this case is 1).
Now, I would like to get this ID on my controller when I call my ajax OR before calling my ajax.

Currently, my ajax is the following:

```
$.post("ajax_edit", {name: _name, age: _age, function(aux){
   console.log(aux);
});
```

Which does not send any parameter with the ID. I was hoping that I might get it by PHP.

```
print_r($this->uri->segment_array());
/* output:  
Array
(
    [1] => dashboard
    [2] => customers
    [3] => edit
    [4] => ajax_edit
) */
```

But unfortunatelly that's what shows to me. So, how can I get that value?

Comment: on this url how you get "ajax_edit" segment http://localhost/proj/dashboard/customers/edit/1

Comment: I went to my route and wrote the following: `$route['dashboard/customers/edit/ajax_edit'] = "customers/ajax_edit";` 
But now that you told me that I'm thinking that I might need something like `(:num)` somehow?

Comment: try (:any) not tested

Comment: It does not work, because it requires that instead of `$.post("ajax_edit")` I use something like `$.post("3/ajax_edit")` or `$.post("ajax_edit/3")` but I don't have that "3"!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Solved** in a different way. Although I really do believe it isn't the best option, I used a session variable.

So in the controller function edit:

```
public function edit(){
  // all code
  $this->session->set_userdata('obj_id', $this->uri->segment(4)); // which is the ID of the customer 
}
```

And then in the ajax_edit function I just have to call that session item.

```
public function ajax_edit(){
  $id = $this->session->userdata('obj_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your route.php config

```
$route['dashboard/customers/edit/(:num)'] = "customers/edit/$1";
```

In your customer.php controller

```
public function edit($user_id) {

    $data['user_id'] = $user_id;
    $this->load->view('NAME_OF_VIEW_FILE', $data);
}
```

In your view file

```
$.post("ajax_edit", {user_id: <?= $user_id ?>, name: _name, age: _age, function(aux){
   console.log(aux);
});
```

I think it's a proper way thant using sessions or playing with uri_segments.

Comment: My javascript code is inside javascript files and not in PHP files, which means (as far as I know) using PHP tags won't work.